# Python, py.test 'HTMLReport' object has no attribute 'execute'

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, pytest, test-reporting

I'm trying to add screenshots to my pytest-html report from automatic tests

i've added to plugin.py:

```
def pytest_runtest_makereport(__multicall__, item):
    report = __multicall__.execute()
    extra = getattr(report, 'extra', [])
    if report.when == 'call':
        xfail = hasattr(report, 'wasxfail')
        if (report.skipped and xfail) or (report.failed and not xfail):
            url = TestSetup.selenium.current_url
            report.extra.append(extras.url(url))
            screenshot = TestSetup.selenium.get_screenshot_as_base64()
            report.extra.append(extras.image(screenshot, 'Screenshot'))
            html = TestSetup.selenium.page_source.encode('utf-8')
            report.extra.append(extra.text(html, 'HTML'))
            report.extra.append(extra.html(html.div('Additional HTML')))
        report.extra = extra
    return report
```

But when running

```
py.test --html=report.html filename.py
```

i get

```
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytest_html\plugin.py", line 288, in pytest_runtest_makereport
INTERNALERROR>     report = __multicall__.execute()
INTERNALERROR> AttributeError: 'HTMLReport' object has no attribute 'execute'
```

Where does it come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by the fact that i've added the pytest_runtest_makereport inside the class. It should be outside. Closed